# How to get dependency tree in browserify?

Tags: browserify

Is there any way to retrieve dependency tree which browserify uses to build bundle?

Browserify takes a bunch of scripts and makes nice bundle of them, resolving all require dependencies. But I want to see structure of that dependencies.

```
var scripts = [ 'a.js', 'b.js' ];//a & b require a lot of other scripts
var b = browserify({
        entries:scripts
    });
b.bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bundle.js'));
//looking on b in debugger I can't find anything like dependency tree
```

Answer (score 3):

This code cribbed from the [`--list` handler in the Browserify `bin/cmd.js` script](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/8f7adc96e3ed59c299d078405a463860f5409ba6/bin/cmd.js#L45-L53) will get you a flat list of files:

```
// Your setup:
var scripts = [ 'a.js', 'b.js' ]; //a & b require a lot of other scripts
var b = browserify({
  entries: scripts
});

// Logging out each of the filenames:
b.pipeline.get('deps').push(require('through2').obj(
  function (row, enc, next) {
    console.log(row.file || row.id);
    next();
  }
));

// Bundle as normal:
b.bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bundle.js'));
```

(Note: You'll need the [`through2` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) installed for the above to work out of the box.)

A tree can be constructed with [the code from the `--deps` handler right next to it](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/8f7adc96e3ed59c299d078405a463860f5409ba6/bin/cmd.js#L35-L43), but all that code does is spit out a list of JSON blobs, each blob containing a list of other files it depends on; you'll need to build the tree yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there are equivalent API methods, but you could try the CLI flags  `--deps` and `--list`.